How does the name group/ring reflect the nature of group/ring as an algebraic structure?
The names group / ring were chosen before we carefully study them. So now in a retrospective way, can we say that these namings capture the good nature of the corresponding algebraic structures? What makes a group like a "group" and a ring like a "ring"? For pedagogic concern, what can we say about the naming when making an introduction of the concepts to help with the intuition?

I stopped worrying about names when they needed a name in foundations  and decided to use "mice"   https://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/talks/bedlewo09.pdf
